# Customuserstore for WSO2 IS 5.9

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I need to create a customeStore using JDBC on similar lines mentioned in the below blog, but for WSO2IS 5.9, so need to know which kernel , versions and all,,,

Please share any blog for the same.

http://isurad.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-write-custom-user-store-manager.html?_sm_au_=iVV3n4ws6PvJnHfMqpT6vK7TWcsMt

Regds,
Subhash

Answer (score 1):

The kernel version of IS 5.9.0 is 4.5.1. (You can refer to the GitHub project pom to refer to other versions if needed https://github.com/wso2/product-is/blob/v5.9.0/pom.xml)

You can also refer to https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/

Comment: What about the datasource and user mgmnt configurations as mentioned in the blog, https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/how-to-write-custom-jdbc-user-store-manager-with-wso2is-4-1-1-alpha/  is it the same way for 5.9.0 as well?

Comment: yes, there are some changes. If you want this user store as the secondary user store then follow this https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/#deploying-and-configuring-the-custom-user-store-manager

Comment: Its the same link, I need to know how to configure the customDatasource? in WSO2 5.9, as mentioned in the blog https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/how-to-write-custom-jdbc-user-store-manager-with-wso2is-4-1-1-alpha/ .

Comment: Refer this https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-user-stores/

Comment: Sorry Senthalan, was looking for customstore for my custom table , so I need to configure my own datasource and as well mention the sqls

Comment: If you are configuring as a secondary user store, then you don't need to configure it as a data source. You need to add it through the management console

Comment: none of the docs are helpful, i see that when I write the customestoremanager and create jar file and place it in the dropins and lib folder,,i will not be able to log in as admin/admin. Even the code snippets in the doc has errors,,,

Comment: it works fine for WSO2 IS 5.3, where as for WSO2 IS 5.9, there are no proper examples or docs to support.

Comment: can you update the question with the configurations you have setup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337316/secondary-userstore-users-unable-to-login-in-wso2-is-5-9  please refer here